# Cartopy aliasing

Tags: cartopy, map-projections

I have the following issue:

When I transform from one map projection to another using Cartopy, the output picture displays a quite ugly aliasing with "steps" larger than one pixel. I attach the input and output pictures as example.

Input - PlateCarree:

[image]

Output - Transformed:

[image]

Could anyone explain me why that happens? Is it possible to correct it?

Comment: Could you please provide code to reproduce? It makes finding a solution much quicker.

Comment: There is a kwarg for GeoAxes.imshow to control the resolution of the reprojected image. It is on the docstring, but not part of the cartopy docs, but you can see it at https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/blob/v0.16.0/lib/cartopy/mpl/geoaxes.py#L1078-L1088. If this works for you, please post your solution as an answer :)

Comment: @pelson Thank you very much! I added "regrid_shape = 3000" as argument to plt.imshow, and it works! Thank you!